# What is the need of an intValue() method if wrappers use unboxing?

Tags: java, integer, wrapper, unboxing

For example, look at this code:

```
Integer myInt = new Integer(5);
int i1 = myInt.intValue();
int i2 = myInt;
    
System.out.println(i1);
System.out.println(i2);
```

As you can see, I have two ways of copying my integer value from the wrapper to the primive:

I can use [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html),

OR

I can use the method [`Integer#intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue()).

So what's the need of having a method when there is already unboxing?

Answer (score 14):

Unboxing was introduced in [Java 5](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0). The wrappers (including this method) have been there since the [original release](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#JDK_1.0).

A link to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29)

In that time (1996) we did need the `intValue()` method and as Oracle guarantees backward backwards  compatibility... up to a certain level (it is not always 100% on major releases).

The method has to stay in.

Comment: So, today I suppose with JDK7 it's better to use unboxing than the old intValue().

Comment: @user1883212 Like DeltaLima shows in his answer, the boxing/unboxing can give some strange results, as long as you know what your are doing feel free to use any of both systems.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Frank's answer which gives a good historical perspective there is still a need to use the `intValue()` today in some situations.

Be aware of the following pitfall that shows that you cannot regard an `Integer` as an `int`:

```
 Integer i1 = new Integer(5);
 Integer i2 = new Integer(5);

 //This would be the way if they were int
 System.out.println(i1 == i2); //Returns false

 //This is the way for Integers
 System.out.println(i1.intValue()==i2.intValue()); //Returns true
 System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); //Returns true
```

Returns

```
false
true
true
```

Comment: Who knows how many puzzled stares and scratched heads this has caused. Fairly typical to run into this unexpectedly when indexing into containers and trying to compare the values. E.g. `List<Integer> A;` `A.get(i) == A.get(i - 1)` returns `false` even though both positions contain `Integer(5)`...

Comment: In modern versions of Java (e.g., 17) this is not valid anymore. It's not possible to instantiate with `Integer i1 = new Integer(5)`. You can only instantiate with `Integer i1 = 5`, and `i1 == i2` will always be `true`. However, for old versions of Java that would be a very good justification for the existence of `intValue()`.